# Spring Integration Complex Correlation Strategy

Tags: java, spring-integration, correlation

I am attempting to use spring-integration to aggregate data from N sources.  In implementing the correlation strategy my understanding is challenged because I do not have a common id that exists between all of the data sources that need to be consumed.  For example:

**Data Source A Message** (MainID, SubIDTwo)

**Data Source B Message** (MainID, SubIDOne, SubIDTwo)

**Data Source C Message** (SubIDOne)

**Data Source D Message** (SubIDTwo)

Taking all of the data sources together the data sets can be consolidated.  However, in the example, Data Source D has no direct mapping to Data Source C.  This mapping can only be achieved using Data Source B.  The receipt time for all of the messages cannot be predicted so in some instances Data Source D's message may arrive before Data Source B and in others Data Source B may arrive before Data Source D.  The expected timing to receive all of the messages can be as long as several hours.  I also cannot rely upon all messages being received so any strategy that depends solely upon a single data source like Data Source B will not address all of the potential conditions.  Most of the samples assume a single common id:

```
public Object getCorrelationKey(Message<?> interactionMessage) {

    MessageHeaders headers = interactionMessage.getHeaders();
    if(headers.containsKey("MAINID")) return headers.get("MAINID");
    return null;
}
```

The reference guide is a bit vague as to how Spring handles the return Object from the correlation strategy.  Can this Object contain attributes for each of the IDs and an Override equal method that returns true if any of the IDs match or is this an invalid approach?

Comment: I need to think about this; nothing immediately comes to mind.

Comment: Sorry for the noise - I think there's a reasonably straightforward technique below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it might be with a custom `MessageGroupStore`.

Message D arrives under group, say `D:bar`

Message C arrives under group, say `C:baz`

Message A arrives under (real) group `foo` - the message store moves message D to group `foo`, deletes group `D:bar`

Message B arrives under (real) group `foo` - the message store moves message C to group `foo`, deletes group `C:baz`

You would also need maps to deal with A,B arriving before C, D - so you know the real group already exists.